# Python variable/count not increasing

Tags: python, download

My code attempts to create a folder which then downloads a pdf to the corresponding folder. In my current code the variable and counter "i" keeps track of which folder to download to but it seems to not be updating for some reason. At the end of the else if statement I want the variable i to increase by 1. Not understanding what the issue is here, I'm fairly new to python and if a similar situation was coded in java I know this would work just file but not sure why it's not working in python.

```
import re
import os
import urllib
f = open("newfile.txt")
suffix = '.pdf'
for line in f:
    i = 0
    folderopt = str(i)


    if suffix in line:
        print('download')
        url = line.rstrip('\n')
        pdfname = url.split('LTN',1)[1]
        print ('download to:'+'/Users/user/Desktop/PDF/'+folderopt+'/'+pdfname)
        urllib.urlretrieve(url,'/Users/user/Desktop/PDF/'+folderopt+'/'+pdfname)
    elif line>i:

        filename = line.rstrip('\n')
        print ('code:'+filename)
        os.mkdir('/Users/user/Desktop/PDF/'+filename)
        global i
        i = i+1
f.close
```

EDIT: I put the variable outside of the for loop still getting this

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/user/Desktop/PDF/0/20160412398.pdf'
```

the i count has not increased even though the folder /Users/user/Desktop/PDF/1 was created.

changed elif statement to

```
elif int(line.rstrip('\n'))>i
```

still not working

Comment: what is the output you're seeing right now? you have print statements -- show some output up there ^^ with your code please.

Comment: You are comparing the string `line` with the integer `i`. That won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You set i to 0 in the loop,try this:

```
import re
import os
import urllib
f = open("newfile.txt")
suffix = '.pdf'
i = 0
for line in f:
    folderopt = str(i)

    if suffix in line:
        print('download')
        url = line.rstrip('\n')
        pdfname = url.split('LTN',1)[1]
        print ('download to:'+'/Users/user/Desktop/PDF/'+folderopt+'/'+pdfname)
        urllib.urlretrieve(url,'/Users/user/Desktop/PDF/'+folderopt+'/'+pdfname)
    elif line>i:

        filename = line.rstrip('\n')
        print ('code:'+filename)
        os.mkdir('/Users/user/Desktop/PDF/'+filename)
        global i
        i+= 1
f.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats because the first line in your loop sets `i` to 0.

Try

```
i = 0
for line in f:
```

instead of

```
for line in f:
    i = 0
```

EDIT:

Also, the `i+=1` should be outside the elif condition, like so

```
elif:
    ...
i+=1
```

not

```
elif:
    ...
    i+=1
```

Comment: attempted i is still not increasing for some reason

Comment: edited, i+=1 should also be outside the elif condition